# Accessing Onedrive/GoogleDrive of Host Windows 10 from guest Virtual Box Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox

I have recently installed Ubuntu on Virtual Box on the host Windows 10.
But now i not able to access the Onedrive, GoogleDrive and Dropbox from Ubuntu.
Please can any body suggest me how to access those folders.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/187703/how-to-access-folders-on-your-host-machine-from-an-ubuntu-virtual-machine-in-virtualbox/